# PHP array merge before create empty value

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
foreach ($ChartData2 as $c3) 
{
    echo $c3->Avr;
}
```

Here is my code and result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi981.png)

I want display like this

```
ApplyMonth |  Avr |  TestCnt
2013-06-01 | 0 |  0
2013-06-01 | 0 |  0
2013-06-03 | 0 |  0
2013-06-04 | 77.8 |  0
...
2013-06-12 | 80.0 |  1
...
2013-06-14 | 50.0 |  1
...
2013-06-30 | 0 |  0
```

How do I create empty value in foreach value?

Comment: Please make it a little clear

Comment: What is your `$ChartData2`?